# Populate a Dropdown in a Dynamic Form in Angular 2

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, field, dropdown

I have this scenario :

This is my FieldDefinition

```
 export interface FieldDefinition {
    key: string,
    type: string,
    isId: boolean,
    label: string,
    required: boolean
 }
```

This is the Dynamic Field definition

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'string'" class="form-group">
  <label [htmlFor]="field.key">{{ field.label }}</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" [formControlName]="field.key" [id]="field.key"
          [readonly]="operation == 'details' || field.isId"></textarea>
</div>

<div *ngSwitchCase="'number'" class="form-group">
  <label [htmlFor]="field.key">{{ field.label }}</label>
  <input class="form-control" [formControlName]="field.key" [id]="field.key" 
          [readonly]="operation == 'details' || field.isId"
          type="number">
</div>

<div *ngSwitchCase="'[]'" class="form-group">
  <label [htmlFor]="field.key">{{ field.label }}</label>
  <select [id]="field.key"
          [formControlName]="field.key">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of field.options"
            [value]="opt.key">
      {{opt.value}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div *ngIf="form.get(field.key).hasError('required') && (submitted || form.get(field.key).touched)"
      class="alert alert-danger">
  {{ field.label }} is required.
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

The ts file :

```
 import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
 import { FieldDefinition } from '../field-definition';

 @Component({
    selector: 'fw-dynamic-field',
    templateUrl: './dynamic-field.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dynamic-field.component.css']
})
export class DynamicFieldComponent {
   @Input() field: FieldDefinition;
   @Input() form: FormGroup;
   @Input() operation: string;
   @Input() submitted: boolean;

   get isValid() { return this.form.controls[this.field.key].valid; }

   constructor() { }
 }
```

The Dynamic Form html

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
 <div *ngFor="let field of vmDefinition">
  <fw-dynamic-field [field]="field" 
                    [form]="form" 
                    [operation]="operation" 
                    [submitted]="submitted">
  </fw-dynamic-field>
</div>

<div *ngIf="errorMessage " class="alert alert-danger">
  {{ errorMessage }}
</div>

<div *ngIf="status != 'waiting'">
  <div *ngIf="operation === 'details'">
    <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onBack()" >Back</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit()" >Edit</button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="operation === 'edit'">
    <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onCancel()" >Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSave()" >Save</button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="operation === 'create'">
    <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onBack()" >Back</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCreate()" >Create</button>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

And the ts file :

```
 export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

 @Input() vm: any;
 @Input() vmDefinition: Array<FieldDefinition>;
 @Input() operation: string;
 @Input() errorMessage: string;
 @Output() update: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 @Output() create: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 form: FormGroup;
 status: string;
 submitted = false;
 vmCopy: any;

  constructor(private router: Router,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private location: Location) { }

  clearForm() {
    const group = {};
    this.vmCopy = Object.assign({}, this.vm);
    this.vmDefinition.forEach(field => {
      group[field.key] = field.required ? new FormControl(this.vmCopy[field.key], Validators.required)
    : new FormControl(this.vmCopy[field.key]);
   });
   this.form = new FormGroup(group);
 }

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     if (changes['errorMessage'].currentValue && this.status === 'waiting') {
      this.status = '';
     }
 }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.clearForm();

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.operation = params['operation'];
       this.clearForm();
     });
 }
```

I'm trying to use this dynamic form in my book-detail page but I'm having problems with populating the dropdown

```
 export class BookDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  book: Book;
  books: IBook[];
  authors: IAuthor[];
  categories: ICategory[];
  errorMessage: string;

  bookDefinition: Array<FieldDefinition> = [
   {
      key: 'bookId',
      type: 'number',
      isId: true,
      label: 'BookId',
      required: true
   },
  {
      key: 'title',
      type: 'string',
      isId: false,
     label: 'Title',
     required: true
  },
  {
     key: 'authors',
     type: '[]',
     isId: false,
     label: 'Authors',
     required: false
  },
  {
     key: 'categories',
     type: '[]',
     isId: false,
     label: 'Categories',
     required: false
  }
];
operation: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
  private bookService: BookService,
  private authorService: AuthorService,
  private categoryService: CategoryService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {

   this.operation = this.route.snapshot.params['operation'];
   this.authorService.getAuthors()
  .subscribe((authors: IAuthor[]) => { this.authors = authors });

   this.categoryService.getCategories()
  .subscribe((categories: ICategory[]) => { this.categories = categories });

  if (this.operation === 'create') {
    this.book = { bookId: 0, title: '', authors: this.authors, categories: 
   this.categories };
  } else {
   this.bookService.getBook(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe((book: Book) => { this.book = book });
 }
}
```

And in the book-detail-component.html I have this

```
 <h3>Book</h3>
<fw-dynamic-form *ngIf='book' [vm]="book" [vmDefinition]="bookDefinition"
[operation]="operation"
[errorMessage]="errorMessage"
(update)="updateBook($event)"
(create)="createBook($event)">
```

It works fine with the other fields but I have problems with the dropdowns for authors and categories. First of all how can I make the getAuthors and getCategories calls in one subscribe ? And then how can I append the values to the dropdowns ? I should create a dropdownField and set it to the field type ? Because I don't have the options property on the field now.. 
Thanks a lot !

UPDATE :

I created this :

```
import { FieldDefinition } from './field-definition';

export class DropdownField extends FieldDefinition {
 type: 'dropdown';
 options: { key: number, value: string }[] = [];

constructor(options: {} = {}) {
  super();
 this.options = options['options'] || [];
 }
 }
```

And I tried to use it in the book-detail-component to populate the dropdown for Authors and the dropdown for Categories

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this.operation = this.route.snapshot.params['operation'];

this.authorService.getAuthors()
  .subscribe((authors: IAuthor[]) => {
    this.authors = authors,
      authors.forEach(function (author) {
      this.authorDropdown.options = [{ key: this.author.authorId, value: this.author.authorName }]
      });
  });

this.categoryService.getCategories()
  .subscribe((categories: ICategory[]) => { this.categories = categories, console.log(this.categories) });

if (this.operation === 'create') {
  this.book = { bookId: 0, title: '', authors: this.authorDropdown, categories: this.categories };
} else {
  this.bookService.getBook(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe((book: Book) => { this.book = book });   
}
}
```

Still doesn't work..

Update 2

```
export class BookDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  book: Book;
  author: Author;
  books: IBook[];
  authors: IAuthor[];
  categories: ICategory[];
  errorMessage: string;

  bookDefinition: Array<FieldDefinition> = [
     {
       key: 'bookId',
       type: 'number',
       isId: true,
       label: 'BookId',
       required: true
     },
     {
       key: 'title',
       type: 'string',
       isId: false,
       label: 'Title',
       required: true
     },
     {
       key: 'authors',
       type: '[]',
       isId: false,
       label: 'Authors',
       required: false
     },
     {
       key: 'categories',
       type: '[]',
       isId: false,
       label: 'Categories',
       required: false
     }
    ];
  operation: string;
  authorDropdown: DropdownField;
  categoryDropdown: DropdownField;

 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private router: Router,
     private bookService: BookService,
     private authorService: AuthorService,
     private categoryService: CategoryService) { }


 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.operation = this.route.snapshot.params['operation'];
    this.authorService.getAuthors()
      .subscribe((authors: IAuthor[]) => {
      this.authors = authors,
      authors.forEach(function (author) {
      this.authorDropdown.options.push({ key: this.author.authorId, value: this.author.authorName });
      });
      console.log(this.authorDropdown);
   });

if (this.operation === 'create') {
  this.book = { bookId: 0, title: '', authors: this.authorDropdown, categories: [] };
} else {
  this.bookService.getBook(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe((book: Book) => { this.book = book });;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me what is exactly the issue i'm confused

Comment: @AbelValdez I cannot populate the dropdown with the values for Authors and Categories, I will update the question with what I've tried since I posted

Comment: @AbelValdez I updated it, the last part :)

Comment: Why you are assign an array in the option var inside of foreach?

Comment: I'm trying to set the key of the dropdown with "authorId" and the value of the dropdown with "authorName". authorDropdown is a DropdownField type. I really don't know what else to try...it crashes here "authors: this.authorDropdown" anyway..

Comment: How can I set the authors property from book to the result of authorService.getAuthors() and the categories property to the result of categoryService.getCategories(), taking into account that I'm using Dynamic Forms ?

Comment: Change it by ...options.push({key...}) to you populate your autors

Comment: But is there any option to do the authorService.getAuthors(), categoryService.getCategories() and bookService.getBook() using only one subscribe ? because even if I manage to populate the authorDropdown and categoryDropdown it will fail here : ( this.book = { bookId: 0, title: '', authors: this.authorDropdown, categories: this.categoryDropdown }; )

Comment: And how can I replace this function : (this.authors.forEach(function (author) {
          this.authorDropdown.options.push({ key: this.author.authorId, value: this.author.authorName });
          });) because it returns "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorDropdown' of undefined"

Comment: It doesnt have sense because you are assigned directly the array you only are assining the last element instead  all array

Comment: And what would be the correct way to do it ? :)

Comment: I added new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct way to do it, your code just add the last element when you are iterating authors array now  you are going to have appended every element from authors here `this.authorDropdown.options` by using `push`.

```
this.authorService.getAuthors()
  .subscribe((authors: IAuthor[]) => {
    this.authors = authors,
      authors.forEach(function (author) {

      this.authorDropdown.options
      .push({ key: this.author.authorId, value: this.author.authorName });        

      });

  });
```

Comment: I tried like this last night but it returns "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorDropdown' of undefined"..although it is declared like this "authorDropdown: DropdownField;"

Comment: Could you post where you are defining `this.authorDropdown` this var

Comment: I posted below "Update 2" :)

Comment: change  `authorDropdown: DropdownField;` for `authorDropdown= new  DropdownField();`